# How to use Powershell to connect to local Azure Storage emulator?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-storage

I'm trying to write a powershell script that creates all of my azure storage containers and stuff, as opposed to manually creating them through some GUI.

I'm looking at the following documentation website, but see no way to connect to my local azure storage service - only the actual azure services.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-powershell

Does anybody know how to, or if it's possible to, connect to the local storage emulator?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Does anybody know how to, or if it's possible to, connect to the local storage emulator?

Yes, you can. For more details, refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azure.storage/new-azurestoragecontext?view=azurermps-6.8.1&viewFallbackFrom=azurermps-6.1.0#examples).

**Note**: You need to run your Storage Emulator first before excute the command.

**Samples**:

1.Create a context by using the local development storage account

```
New-AzureStorageContext -Local
```

2.Get the container for the local developer storage account

```
New-AzureStorageContext -Local | Get-AzureStorageContainer
```

3.Create a new container

```
New-AzureStorageContext -Local | New-AzureStorageContainer -Name <containername>
```

Comment: Note that since Joy wrote this the powershell cmdlets have changed name. You now need New-AzStorageXXX instead of New-AzureStorageXXX. Generally you can replace Azure with Az and it should work.

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to update this answer rather than add a new one?

Answer (score 2):

Powershell syntax has been updated since 2018.

The new cmdlets use the prefix Az instead of Azure so:

`New-AzStorageContext -Local | Get-AzStorageContainer`

`New-AzStorageContext -Local | New-AzStorageContainer -Name <containername>`